# Select datetime and value, when value != LAG(value)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm working on SQL Server 2014.

I have data like:

```
datetime                      Value
2020-11-27 11:20:20.0000000   0
2020-11-27 11:21:20.0000000   0
2020-11-27 11:22:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:23:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:24:20.0000000   2
2020-11-27 11:25:20.0000000   2
2020-11-27 11:26:20.0000000   2
2020-11-27 11:27:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:28:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:29:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:30:20.0000000   2
2020-11-27 11:31:20.0000000   null
2020-11-27 11:32:20.0000000   2
```

I need:

```
datetime                      Value
2020-11-27 11:20:20.0000000   0
2020-11-27 11:22:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:24:20.0000000   2
2020-11-27 11:27:20.0000000   1
2020-11-27 11:30:20.0000000   2
2020-11-27 11:31:20.0000000   null
2020-11-27 11:32:20.0000000   2
```

I can have hundred thousand rows, so I also need something efficient. I tried to work with `LAG()`, `rank()`, `first()`, but I never get expected result.

Comment: Please explain the logic of your expected result.

Comment: *"I tried to work with `LAG()`, `rank()`, `first()`, but I never get expected result."* Then show us those attempts and explain why they didn't work. `first()` is also not a T-SQL function.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The required logic is in the post title

Comment: @iamdave To me that sounds like an attempted implementation that didn't work. Verbally explaining the desired solution is helpful because it gives a different frame of the problem than a purely solution-oriented description.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  And yet, if you apply that logic to the example data you get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `LAG()`:

```
SELECT [datetime], [value]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      [datetime], [value],
      LAG([value]) OVER (ORDER BY [datetime] ASC) AS [prevvalue]
   FROM (VALUES
      ('2020-11-27T11:20:20.0000000', 0),
      ('2020-11-27T11:21:20.0000000', 0),
      ('2020-11-27T11:22:20.0000000', 1),
      ('2020-11-27T11:23:20.0000000', 1),
      ('2020-11-27T11:24:20.0000000', 2),
      ('2020-11-27T11:25:20.0000000', 2),
      ('2020-11-27T11:26:20.0000000', 2),
      ('2020-11-27T11:27:20.0000000', 1),
      ('2020-11-27T11:28:20.0000000', 1),
      ('2020-11-27T11:29:20.0000000', 1),
      ('2020-11-27T11:30:20.0000000', 2),
      ('2020-11-27T11:31:20.0000000', null),
      ('2020-11-27T11:32:20.0000000', 2)
   ) v ([datetime], [value])   
) t
WHERE COALESCE([value], -1) <> COALESCE([prevvalue], -1)
```

Result:

```
datetime                    value
2020-11-27T11:20:20.0000000 0
2020-11-27T11:22:20.0000000 1
2020-11-27T11:24:20.0000000 2
2020-11-27T11:27:20.0000000 1
2020-11-27T11:30:20.0000000 2
2020-11-27T11:31:20.0000000 null
2020-11-27T11:32:20.0000000 2
```